# What could it be the white fatty substance I found in raisins?

Tags: fruit, fat

[image]

[image]

Hi, as you can see in the pictures, strange white, fatty substance collects in raisins irregularities. May it be something natural origin or could it be that producer dumped these in palm oil to make them shiny? Is it safe to consume?

I have tried to ask the producer, unfortunately no answer was given :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vast majority of dried vine fruits are coated in one vegetable oil or another. The ones I’ve seen which name the oil tend to use sunflower oil or cottonseed oil. They use them to prevent the vine fruits clumping.

Sunmaid are one of the few mass producers which declare that they don’t use oils or glazes.